# A diagram with a rounding arrow

Tags: xy-pic, commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to do a diagram like [this](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cfnn2jeUMAEQqrC.jpg) in xy-pic. I'm able to do all the diagram, EXCEPT by the long arrow of $\bar{\varphi}|_P\chi$. Is it possible to generate an arrow like that? At this point I only have this part of the code:

```
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
& P\ar[ldd]^{\chi} \ar[rrrdd]^{\varphi^{-1}\circ\psi}  && \\
\\
P\ar[rr]^{\bar{\varphi}\vert_P}&& P'\ar[uul]_{\varphi} \ar[rr]^{\psi} && P' \\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, give us a MWE. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using tikz and xy  (it is not exactly the same) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
& \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node[name=pstart] {};P\ar[ldd]^{\chi} \ar[rrrdd]^{\varphi^{-1}\circ\psi}  && \\
\\
P\ar[rr]^{\bar{\varphi}\vert_P}&& \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node[name=pend] {};P'\ar[uul]_{\varphi} \ar[rr]^{\psi} && P' \\}
\]

\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw[red,->] (pstart.west) to[out=180,in=90] (1.5,.5) to[out=-90,in=-90] (pend.south);


\[
  \xymatrix{
    & P\ar[ldd]^{\chi} \ar[rrrdd]^{\varphi^{-1}\circ\psi} \ar@/_8pc/[rdd] && \\
    \\
    P\ar[rr]^{\bar{\varphi}\vert_P}&& P'\ar[uul]_{\varphi} \ar[rr]^{\psi} && P' \\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not possible with xy? (Thanks for the answer)

Comment: Yes I think it is possible : http://math.arizona.edu/~swig/documentation/xypic/Xypic.pdf But I don't know very well

Answer (score 2):

Also with Ti*k*Z (or say, `tikz-cd`) but this needs only one compilation:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
& P\arrow{dl}{\chi}\arrow{drrr}{\varphi^{-1}\circ\psi}\arrow[out=180,in=225, looseness=4,red]{dr} & & & \\
P\arrow{rr}{\bar{\varphi}\vert_P} & & P'\arrow{ul}[swap]{\varphi}\arrow{rr}{\psi} & & P'
\end{tikzcd}
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]